# How to consume Custom pipe defined in a angular library?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, angular-library

I am facing issue while importing a custom pipe from angular library to main app.It is a custom library and I am using static forroot approach to load the library's module.I have declared and exported the pipe in library and also have imported custom library in the main app module.But unfortunately, a try to use the pipe is failing with error 'customPipe' could not be found in the 'AppComponent'.
Here is project structure:

- src

  - app

    - app.module.ts
    - app.component.ts
- library

  - src

    - lib

      - pipes

        custom.pipe.ts
      - customlib.module.ts

    public-api.ts

Sharing the code here:

customPipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'customPipe'
})
export class customPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(){}
  transform(value1: string,value2:string): unknown {
    return value1+value2
  };
}
```

customlib.module.ts

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { customPipe } from 'path to customPipe'
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    customPipe
  ]
  ,exports: [customPipe]
})

export class customLibraryModule {
  constructor (@Optional() @SkipSelf() module: customLibraryModule) {
    if (module) {
      throw new Error(
        'custom is already loaded.Import it in the AppModule only.');
    }
  }

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<customLibraryModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: customLibraryModule,
      providers: [
       {provide:'service',useValue:customService},// not of any use here for my usecase
      ]
    };
  }
```

public-api.ts

```
export { customPipe } from 'path to CustomPipe';
export * from './lib';
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    ],
    imports: [
        customLibraryModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<div>
    {{'test' | customPipe:'value1' : 'value2'}}
  </div>
```

app.component is not able to find customPipe and throws *"customPipe could not be found in the 'app.component'"*.

Please help to fix the issue .Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the library directly in the imports array, that will load the exports of the module, `forRoot` will load the providers I think!

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    ],
    imports: [
        customLibraryModule,    // <-- changed here!
        customLibraryModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```